# How do I read the content of every HTML tag using Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping, mechanize

How do I write a Mechanize scraper to get the content from every HTML tag on a web page? Or do I need to convert the page to a string and use regex to get all the content between `\<.*?\>` and `\<\/.*?\>`?

Answer (score 2):

To find more information regarding writing a web scraper with Mechanize take a look at the following tutorials:

- http://readysteadycode.com/howto-scrape-websites-with-ruby-and-mechanize
- http://www.icicletech.com/blog/web-scraping-with-ruby-using-mechanize-and-nokogiri-gems

Also keep in mind that mechanize uses the [Nokogiri gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri) to do its underlying scraping. If you are not attached to Mechanize consider just using Nokogiri to parse the HTML tags.

Do not convert the page to a string and use regex to get the HTML content. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for more information on why that is a bad idea.

## --Edit--

As @pguardiario mentioned in the comment below, the code to get all the content for each tag is `page.search(*).map &:text`

Comment: @Зелёный fair enough, I have improved the answer to provide a more useful answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm literally trying to go through the content of every tag on a we page. Is there a way to do this with Mechanize/Nokogiri?

Comment: The short answer is yes there is a way to do that. Do you need to separate the content into a data structure based on which tag it was in or do you just want the plain text all jumbled together?

Comment: (Also if my answer helped don't forget to click the green check to accept it)

Comment: For each tag, I want the content in plain text. I have not yet found a way to do this with Mechanize or Nokogiri.

Comment: That would be `page.search(*).map &:text`

Answer (score 1):

Do you limited only to mechanize?
Maybe, you can try to use watir or pure selenium to get web page with all tags in one object.

Comment: How would I do that in Selenium?